# Using Tunnelbroker to load balance Node.JS web scraper

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, node.js, scraping

I was wondering if I could assign my Linux VPS that is hosting my Node.JS app (puppeteer) for web scraping with a block of IPv6 addresses from [Tunnelbroker](https://tunnelbroker.net/) to achieve IP rotation and load-balance my scraping requests and minimize the chances of the application getting blocked by websites.

Comment: Technically yes, but in practice the websites will just block the entire /64 and then the entire /48. You're not the first person to abuse tunnel services that way.

Comment: @user1686 I understand the risks of getting blocked by using and rotating through ipv6 blocks. Would you mind showing me a practical way of how I may go about doing it?